# Unknown column od.id_warehouse in where clause

Tags: mysql, php, mvcc

```
SELECT LEFT(invoice_date, 10) as fix_date, 
       COUNT(*) as countOrders, 
       SUM((SELECT SUM(od.product_quantity) FROM ps_order_detail od WHERE o.id_order = od.id_order)) as countProducts, 
       SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl / o.conversion_rate) as totalSales 
FROM ps_orders o 
WHERE o.valid = 1 
AND  od.id_warehouse = 5
AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-09-30 23:59:59' 
AND o.id_shop IN (1) 
GROUP BY LEFT(invoice_date, 10)
```

I want to connect between table order and order_detail by left join but when I add left join occur an error in the title what solution? I want to connect between table order and order_detail by left join but when I add left join occur an error in the title what solution?

I want to connect between table order and order_detail by left join but when I add left join occur an error in the title what solution?

Comment: I want to connect between table order and order_detail by left join but when I add left join occur an error in the title what solution?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Please read the link and update the question. There is no `od.id_warehouse` because you should join with ps_order_detail `FROM ps_orders o LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail ....`

Comment: thank s my dear this syntax is one stament

Comment: and id_warehouse  column in ps_order_detail